# Load specific trained model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

Currently I am loading a previously trained model using

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
```

which loads the file recorded in the file "checkpoint" that was created when saving the model. However, the file "checkpoint" always refers to the last trained model, so if I want to load another model I have to manually edit the "checkpoint" file to change the model name.

My question is, how can I restore a trained model different from the last one I created, without manually editing the "checkpoint" file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jsonpickle to save variables and models and later load them.
For example:

```
sklearn_model = RandomForestClassifier()
sklearn_model.fit(x,y)
model_object = jsonpickle.pickler.Pickler.flatten(sklearn_model)
model = jsonpickle.unpickler.Unpickler.restore(model_object)
model.predict(new_x)
```

All you need now is to save the model whenever you want, and load it as needed. the model_object is a JSON code that can be saved to a file. You can read more about the package [here](https://jsonpickle.github.io/api.html)

Comment: Hi @Roee, can you tell how to save this model_object to use later for prediction?

Comment: @AmarpreetSingh see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398078/saving-and-loading-objects-from-file-using-jsonpickle